# ソケットのsend()の使い方とオーバーヘッドについて

Tags: linux, c++, socket, tcp, 非同期

C++で非同期通信を実装しています。環境はLinux(今のところUbuntuとCentOSが前提)。
このクラスを使用する側は、任意のタイミングで好きなだけsend()を使える仕様で考えています。

```
例：
myAsyncClass myAsync;
myAsync.connect("host");

myAsync.send(buf1,len1);  // ←非同期で処理されてすぐリターンする.
myAsync.send(buf2,len2);  // ←非同期で処理されてすぐリターンする.
myAsync.send(buf3,len3);  // ←非同期で処理されてすぐリターンする.

// 受信はあらかじめ登録したコールバックか何かで行う.
```

内部でソケットが書き込み可能になったらシステムコールのsend()を呼びます。
しかし、なるべくシステムコールの呼び出し回数は少ない方が良いため、書き込み可能になった時にbuf1とbuf2とbuf3を全て持っていたら、それらを連結して一回だけsend()を呼ぼうかと思っています。

ですが、buf1とbuf2とbuf3のメモリを連結するためには、buf1の末尾(あるいは自分で用意した別バッファ)へ動的確保を行い、buf2とbuf3をコピーするコストが発生します。

ここで迷っているのは、メモリの確保とコピーを行うくらいなら、素直にsend()を3回呼んだ方がコストが少ないのではないか？ということです。

このあたりの知見をお持ちの方がいらしたらアドバイスお願いします。
もちろんケースバイケースで、コピーする頻度や量にもよるという意見もあるかと思いますが。。

Comment: BSD socketのsend(write)を直接利用する前提ですか？例えば[Boost.Asioライブラリ](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/)は非同期送信もサポートしています。

Comment: boostも検討はしていますが、依存ライブラリを少なくしたいので今のところは使わない予定です。

Comment: マルチプラットフォームライブラリの利用をさけるならば、前提とするOS等を明記された方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: 失礼しました。環境を追記しました。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ソケットの通信の効率化をネットワークカードレベルで考える](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9375) の回答にある、

> scatter/gather I/Oまたはvectored I/Oと呼ばれる機構

これがまさにその、まとめて実行するものです。
Linuxのstruct iovec や、Winsockの WSABuf は 簡単に言えば (*buf, len) の構造体で、sendmsgやWSASendではその配列を含む引数を渡すことにより、複数の(*buf, len)を一度に処理します。

性能が変わるかどうかはアプリケーションによるので、実測比較してくださいとしか言えません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

使い方はこちらですね。
http://linuxjm.sourceforge.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man2/readv.2.html
戻り値が普通のsend()と同じ意味なのでさほど変更なく使えそうです。

自身のクラスのキューにいったん溜めて、ソケットが書き込み可能になったら、この方法を送信することを検討してみます。

Comment: OpenSSLのssl_write()で同様のAPIは用意されているのでしょうか？
かるく検索したところ、自前でバッファを連結している実装がいくつかヒットしました。

Comment: @0xfffffff7  SSL_writev 相当の API は存在しないため、自前でバッファ連結してから SSL_write を呼び出す必要があります