# TCPコネクションを1本保持するのと10本保持する場合のコストの違い

Tags: tcp, network

同じ内容を一本の接続に全て書き込むのと、10本に対して書き込むのは、どのくらいCPUサイクルやリソース消費が違いますか？
速度や通信効率は置いておいて、マシン負荷のみを考えた場合に一本の方がコストが少ないのでしょうか？

Comment: クライアント側プログラムの挙動としてどうか？という質問ですか？さらに同一サーバに対する通信、ということでよいですか？

Comment: 同一サーバーへのリクエストの話です。
主にクライアント側の話として考えていますが、上記の場合のサーバーにかかる負荷についての知見をお持ちの方がいらしたらそれも合わせてコメント頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マシン負荷を考える場合、CPUよりも低速なデバイスとのやり取りにコストがかかります。受信パケットがあればCPUに割り込みが発生しますから、TCPコネクション数に応じて負荷が上がると考えていいでしょう。
送信に関しても[ソケットの通信の効率化をネットワークカードレベルで考える](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/9473/4236)でコメントしましたが今はネットワークカードにオフロード処理させるためコネクション数が少ない方が処理をまとめることができます。

Answer (score -3):

ネットワークカードのハードウエアレベルでできることはネットワークカードに任せれば CPU 負荷は減ります。
その意味で、同時に複数の通信をしないほうが負荷は小さいです。

あえてマシン負荷以外の話をしてみると
１クライアントが１サーバに対して同時に複数のコネクションを張ること自体が犯罪レベルの悪です。
１クライアントが１サーバに対して１０本のコネクションを同時に張るということは、サーバ側の空きポートを１０個消費するということです。
サーバ側空きポートが１００個しかない場合を想定します。クライアントが
１コネクションを張る仕様だと１００人が同時に使用できるのに、
１０コネクションを張る仕様だと１０人しか同時に使用することができません。
(実際には TIME_WAIT 状態に陥るはずで、もっと少ない人数しか使えないでしょう)
サーバーポート枯渇って奴です。

Comment: HTTPで6本張る場合がありませんか？

Comment: 古きよき http1.0 は原則、毎回コネクション１本を張り、切断する仕様です。
でもコネクション数を増やしてかつ Keep-Alive するほうが毎回接続切断するより負荷が少ないことがわかってきたので http も複数コネクションを張るように変遷してきました。
現代 web ブラウザは複数コネクションを張るのが一般的なようです。
これが可能になったのはサーバ側の機能増強が進んだおかげですね。

Comment: サーバーに複数のクライアントが接続したところで、80番なら80番だけであって、サーバー側のポートは消費されないように思います。（そのサーバが別のサーバにクライアントとして接続するなら別ですが）

Comment: @Ripple 
> 接続用の別ポートを開いて通信します
HTTPサーバーの話ですか？
どこかにその事が書いてある記事などはありますでしょうか？

Comment: ポートが占有される話と、ディスクリプタが消費される話がごっちゃになってませんかね。どれだけの数のクライアントが同時に接続しても、サーバ側で占有されるポート（0〜65535までの16bitの値）は、Listenしているポートだけです（accept した後でもクライアント毎に Destination port が変わりなんてしませんよね）。一方で、ディスクリプタやTCB（TCP Control Block）は消費されるので、有限なリソースの一部が消費されることは確かです。